# Two columns layout in Quarto

Tags: text, layout, multiple-columns, quarto

**Quarto**

I am creating a website in `Quarto` and would like to have a two columns layout so I can nicely show text side by side. In [`streamlit`](https://streamlit.io) you can use [`columns`](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/layout/st.columns) to get a two columns layout. Here is an example code of how to layout should look like:

```
---
title: "Two columns layout Quarto"
format: 
  html:
    code-fold: true
engine: knitr
---

I would like to have text here                                               and here

Sentence becomes longer, it should automatically stay in their column        More text
```

Output:

---

[image]

---

As you can see the text is combined into one sentence, while I would like to have it separately like a two columns layout. So I was wondering if this is possible in `Quarto`?

**Streamlit**

Here is an example in `streamlit`:

```
# Package
import streamlit as st

# Function with columns
def txt(a, b):
    col1, col2 = st.columns([7,2])
    with col1:
        st.markdown(a)
    with col2: 
        st.markdown(b)

# Example
st.write('# Example in Streamlit')
txt('I would like to have text here', 'and here')
```

Output:

---

[image]

---

As you can see this is nicely shown in two column layout.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use pandoc `.columns` div to create column layout

```
---
title: "Two columns layout Quarto"
format: 
  html:
    code-fold: true
engine: knitr
---

:::: {.columns}

::: {.column width="70%"}
I would like to have text here

Sentence becomes longer, it should automatically stay in their column
:::

::: {.column width="10%"}
<!-- empty column to create gap -->
:::

::: {.column width="20%"}
and here

More text
:::

::::
```

---

[image: Two column layout]

---

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively, you could utilize the [bootstrap css grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/css-grid/) for such kind of questions. You would not need an additional empty column to create space, you could change columns gaps easily (see [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/css-grid/#columns-and-gaps)):

```
---
title: "Two columns layout Quarto"
format: html
engine: knitr
---
  
  
::: {.grid}

::: {.g-col-6}

## First column 
I would like to have text here

Sentence becomes longer, it should automatically stay in their column
:::
  
::: {.g-col-6}

## Second column 

and here

More text

:::
  
:::
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the command `layout-ncol=2` as explained in [Figure Panels](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/figures.html#figure-panels) of the Quarto documentation:

### Two columns layout Quarto (Version 1)

```
---
title: "Two columns layout Quarto"
format: html
engine: knitr
---

::: {layout-ncol=2}


**First column**

**Second column** 

I would like to have text here

and here

Sentence becomes longer, it should automatically stay in their column

More text

:::
```

[image]

Between every paragraph (here sentence) there needs to be an empty line. It may sound strange that this explanation is in the chapter about figures. But as it explained under [Figure Divs](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/figures.html#figure-divs):

> You can treat any markdown content you want as a figure by enclosing it in Pandoc div block …

### Two columns layout Quarto (Version 2)

Under the heading [Custom Layouts](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/figures.html#complex-layouts) the Quarto documentation also explains a more general approach: Instead of using `layout-ncol` or `layout_nrow` where all columns are of the same size, you can also create more complex designs with the `layout` attribute. In the example of the OP the first column has more text than the second column, so we could for instance to specify a column distribution of 2:1.

```
---
title: "Two columns layout Quarto"
format: html
engine: knitr
---

::: {layout="[[10,5], [40,20], [26,13], [2,1]]"}


**First column**

**Second column**

I would like to have text here

and here

Sentence becomes longer, it should automatically stay in their column

More text

:::
```

[image]

Note that the used row / column numbers in the second example are arbitrary. They just provide the desired proportion of 2:1. The code translates to "create four rows, where the first column has always the double size of the second column."

Comment: In your first example, with `layout-ncol=2`, why is the default width not 50%-50%?

Comment: The default width for a column is 100% divided by the number of columns.

Comment: So it should be 50-50, but it looks more like 70-30 (in version 1)