# Span figure across columns in Quarto docx output

Tags: multiple-columns, docx, quarto

I am making an article in quarto, for which I need a word (docx) output file. The article should be in 2 column format. To achieve the 2 column output in word, I referred to the answer given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76452715/21281335). Here the answer involved making sections within the .qmd file using office open XML. Since I know nothing about this, I blindly copied the answer and it works well. My practice document looks like this:

[image: practice document]

In the document, I inserted some figures(test figures) to see how it would look, and when I need the figures within a column, the above approach works well. The problem is when I have a bigger figure that I need to span across the 2 columns. I need the figure to span the 2 columns while the text part still keeps the 2 column format. Could anyone please help with this ?

Since I don't know anything about open office XML, I have no idea what to try. For one, I tried to close the 2 column section before the image to be spanned, and then opened a new 2 column section after the image. But this lead to the image being placed on a fresh page, and a lot of empty space in the page above, as shown:

[image: outcome]

I think maybe there is a way to make a full span section within the 2 column section, to put the image, but I don't really know how. Please help

EDIT : After some searching around, there is a workaround where after generating the word document, we can change the "wrap text" property of the picture, and get it to span the 2 columns.
To do this programmatically, it looks like we need to create a "continuous section break" I think, but I don't understand how to do this